# Jquery validate number range

Tags: jquery-validate

I want to set the valid number from  -1 to infinity in the jquery validate rules, but how should i specify the number range.  In **from** i specified  "-1" and its working but in **to** what should be the value.

```
rules: {
                "numberOfUsers": {
                    "required": true,
                    "number":true,
                    "range":[-1,1000]
                }
```

--
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infinity is displayed when a number exceeds the upper limit of the floating point numbers, which is 1.7976931348623157E+10308.

rewrite your rules like this

```
rules: {
                "numberOfUsers": {
                    "required": true,
                    "number":true,
                    "range":[-1,1.7976931348623157E+10308]
                }
```

or simply use this

```
rules: {
                    "numberOfUsers": {
                        "required": true,
                        "number":true,
                        "range":[-1,Infinity]
                    }
```

Comment: If you want to do this, why not use `Infinity` itself?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Also just curious, can we specify a series of range instead of using regex, like -1, & 1 - Infinity skipping zero i.e., zero is invalid value.

Comment: if you want to skip zero when you loop thru the range if zero occurs just use continue; statement from your loop to skip zero

Comment: Do i have to write a "customValidation" method?

Comment: something like this --                     "required": function(element){
                       if($("#org-users-input").val() === 0){
                          return false; 
                       }